# How do I check whether a Local Publication exists given the publication name and how do I delete it along with everything associated with it?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, replication

I'm working in ASP .NET and I need to do a couple of things:

1. Check whether the Publication I'm about to create already exists.
2. If it does, delete it along with EVERYTHING related to it (jobs, etc. including anything at the subscriber side).

I started with this:

```
public static bool PublicationExists(string server)
        {
            string finalConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.rawConnectionString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server).Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(finalConnString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("what is the query to check whether a publication exists?", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (var ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            da.Fill(ds);

                            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now...

```
If (PublicationExists(server) == true)
{
    //I want to delete the publication along with everything associated with it.
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Under the "Replication Folder" there is the "Local Publications" folder. Under this folder you'll find the Publications. Is there a way I can query for a specific Publication Name? "select name from X where name = "Publication Name"

Comment: but what's the query? lol ... i dont know what system tables hold publication information...

Comment: dude you are confusing me haha. say I have a publication on server X called "blahblah" .....how do I check whether "blahblah" exists on server X by running a query?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17523/discussion-between-thousand-and-testifier)